# Pandas: Last time when a column had a non-nan value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's assume that I have the following data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "nominal": [1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan], "numeric1": [3, np.nan, np.nan, 7, np.nan], "numeric2": [2, 3, np.nan, 2, np.nan], "numeric3": [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3], "date":[pd.Timestamp(2005, 6, 22), pd.Timestamp(2006, 2, 11), pd.Timestamp(2008, 9, 13), pd.Timestamp(2009, 5, 12), pd.Timestamp(2010, 5, 9)]})
```

As output, I want to get a data-frame, that will indicate the number of days that have passed since a non-nan value was seen for that column, for that `id`. If a column has a value for the corresponding date, or if a column doesn't have a value at the start for an new `id`, the value should be a 0. In addition, this is supposed to be computed only for the numeric columns. With that said, the output data-frame should be:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame({"numeric1_delta": [0, 234, 1179, 0, 362], "numeric2_delta": [0, 0, 945, 0, 362], "numeric3_delta": [0, 0, 945, 0, 0]})
```

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Will it have like numeric1 = 1 NaN 1 NaN 2 NaN NaN ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby the cumsum of the non null and then subtract the first date:

```
In [11]: df.numeric1.notnull().cumsum()
Out[11]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
Name: numeric1, dtype: int64

In [12]: df.groupby(df.numeric1.notnull().cumsum()).date.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[12]:
0   2005-06-22
1   2005-06-22
2   2005-06-22
3   2009-05-12
4   2009-05-12
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: df.date - df.groupby(df.numeric1.notnull().cumsum()).date.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[13]:
0      0 days
1    234 days
2   1179 days
3      0 days
4    362 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

For multiple columns:

```
ncols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("numeric")]

for c in ncols:
    df[c + "_delta"] = df.date - df.groupby(df[c].notnull().cumsum()).date.transform('first')
```

Comment: transform('first')

Comment: Can you adjust your answer to work on all columns that contain the string `numeric` in them?

Comment: I will accept the answer because it is definitely what I had included in the question. However, I updated the example where I included one more column. I will appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: @gorjan looks like the for loop should work there too, but please ask another question if there's something different :)

Comment: Well everything is the same. The only addition being that if there is a `NaN` value at the start of a column, the value should be 0.

Comment: @gorjan I am getting 0 when I run my code, so not sure I understand the issue

Comment: I have updated your answer. I wanted the time difference for each column, to be applied per `id`.